# How to open pop-up window in ASP.NET web application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web, popup

I'm using a GridView in ASP.NET web application and want to open something like a "new form" (like in Windows Forms application) which will contain the selected GridView row data. I don't have issues selecting the row and the data, I just want to know how to open a new pop-up window, or secondary page or something like that, and how to pass the information to newly opened pop-up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Years ago I wrote a simple tutorial on that:

http://netpl.blogspot.com/2007/12/autocompleteextender-key-value-issue.html

http://netpl.blogspot.com/2007/12/autocompleteextender-and-key-value.html

Comment: thanks, reading it now, one question, is there any way of invoking double click event on datagrid ? to open childwindow?

Comment: You possibly could use javascript, however - I would prefer a separate button to trigger the operation. Web application users are probably not used to implicit actions triggered by double clicks.

Comment: I understand, I've looked up your first link, and I managed to return the value I wanted from the childpage to the parent page, but how can i send data from the parent page to the child page?

Comment: You can pass the data in the querystring of the newly created child window.